# elsarticle: problems with \begin{cases}

Tags: elsarticle

The following simple code does not compile with Texlive 2016

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
$$\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}(\xi^j)^i=\begin{cases}
d &\text{si }j=0\\
0 &\text{sinon}.
\end{cases}$$
\end{document}
```

With `amsart` class, everything is OK. Any hint or idea to solve this problem is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, please consider making a full but minimal working example as explained in [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2288).

Comment: Package `amsmath` is missing. `elsarticle` doesn't load it (as `amsart` does.

Comment: Simply load `amsmath`(or, better `mathtools`: you'll have improved cases variants). Also don't use the syntax `$$ … $$`: it's plain TeX syntax, and you'll have bad spacing.

Comment: To the comments of Bernard, Zarko and Diaa, you use `\[...\]` instead `$$...$$`.